# Webdriver manager update fails on version 10.0.2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

I updated webdriver-manager from version 10.0.1 to version 10.0.2, and since then I get the following error when I run the update command:

```
$ webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 10.0.2
[09:10:50] E/config - nothing to return for a config file

assert.js:89
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:352:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Function.Config.binaryVersions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/config.js:82:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/binaries/chrome_driver.js:47:51
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/binaries/chrome_driver.js:51:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I get this both locally and on travis. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Got same issue, downgrade to 10.0.1 works - `npm i -g webdriver-manager@10.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the history on these releases. The first working release that Protractor used was webdriver-manager 10.0.4. I believe 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 still had a few issues. Please use the latest. The latest release is 12.0.4 and it should have the fix for this issue.